# VBA - Run the macro from a workbook with all modules protected with password

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a macro from a workbook that has all its module protected with a known password. I am using the Application.Run function, but I do not know if it will be possible to input the password (It certainly doesn't sound safe to hard-code the password in the function).

So I am wondering if there is a way to do it.

I searched the forum and I know there is already a post on this, but there is no syntax/example for Application.Run, and I tried Application.Run("'WorkbookName'!MacroName", Password:="password"), and it gave me a syntax error.

MSDN doesn't have an example on this either.

------------------------------------------more detail on the problem---------------------------------------------------------

I have workbook1, which contains a line `Application.Run ("'workbook2'!CopyDown")`

I can run CopyDown in workbook2 and have no issue.

However, when I run the line from workbook1, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error'1004':
Sorry, we could not find [path to workbook1, which is opened by the macro in the previous lines]. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

I checked the inside the modules of workbook2, and I do have a subprocedure called "CopyDown".

Comment: If you're talking about a VBProject "view" password - that is only required to see the actual code - it should not be needed to run a method.  If you mean something else then you need to be more specific.

Comment: "safe to hard-code" -- VBProject protection isn't "safe" either - it's easily defeated in a fraction of a second. In any case a protected project doesn't require you to enter a password to run. There's no such feature.

Comment: The syntax error is because the parentheses are redundant and making their entire contents `(foo, bar)` being evaluated as a value - which is illegal, since the parenthesized expression doesn't evaluate to anything. Drop the parentheses and you'll get a different error, for the `Password` named argument being non-existent.

Comment: @TimWilliams That's also my suspicion. When I ran the code sometime earlier today, the macro ran fine. But now, it is giving me an error: Run-time error '1004' Sorry, we couldn't find [the path to the workbook, which is already opened]. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted? I will add further detail on my problem.

Comment: I have added more detail on the problem that I initially thought was due to password protection.

Comment: Are you sure both workbooks are open in the same instance of excel?  Try using the full filename (including the extension) e.g.  `Application.Run "'workbook2.xlsm'!CopyDown"`

Comment: @TimWilliams I will try that. But I didn't specifically open another instance of Excel, and I am able to see all modules in the same VBE window.

Comment: Is the error coming from the code in the `CopyDown` method?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't think so. When I hit Debug, the line `Application.Run ("'workbook2'!CopyDown")` is highlighted. It doesn't go into the CopyDown method, so I don't think the run-time error is coming from the method itself.

Comment: If the called macro is password-protected then you won't be able to debug it, so it may highlight the calling line..  The error you mention says the missing file is workbook1 - that doesn't seem related to your call to `workbook2'!CopyDown`.  We are missing some information here I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams Maybe this is an instance where VBE is giving unhelpful error messages? I have the password to the CopyDown procedure, and it doesn't open any files. I'll keep looking. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: If you unlock the VB project does it still error in the same place?

Comment: @TimWilliams I see that the problem is not with the passwords. I have two macros in workbook2, and I call both of them. One of them runs fine, but the other one gives the error mentioned in the post. The only differences I can see between the two macros are 1. The name of the macro that gives error has "Public Sub" in front of it as opposed to only "Sub". 2. The macro that gives an error has the same name as the module that contains the macro. I deleted the "Public" key word, didn't help. I changed the name of the subprocedure to something else, and the code ran fine. Don't know what happened.

Comment: Well at least you fixed it...   Likely not a good idea to give a Sub the same name as a module though.

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't know how the problem went away. Possible it will reappear in the future? In my defense, I wasn't the one who named the sub the same name as the module. Thanks for your help!